# How to swap first and last name with specific formatting

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I want to swap first and last name value. I have the following:

> **Max Keller** and I want to retrieve **Keller,Max**

I don't really know how to handle this as I am a beginner in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `REGEXP_REPLACE` function comes in handy here:

```
SELECT
    orig_name,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(orig_name, '^([^ ]+) (.*)$', '$2,$1')
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    orig_name ~* '^[^ ]+ [^ ]+$';
```

This answer assumes that there is only a single first and last name word, with no middle names, suffices, etc.

Comment: Is there a way I can remove the space after the last name, from Keller, Max to Keller,Max.

Comment: Yes, just use the replacement `$2,$1`, with no spaces anywhere.

Comment: Cool, thanks, is it possible to handle cases where there are middle names included. For example cases like 'Max Henry Keller, would translate to Keller,Max Henry

Comment: Handling anything other than strictly first + last name is very tricky, and a can of worms.  I won't even attempt to cover all such edge cases.  If you have this requirement, then you should show examples for _all_ possible types of names.

Comment: To explain why it gets tricky, some people have two word first names, two word middle names, two word last names.  Without well defined rules, it gets out of hand quickly.

Comment: I understand, is there a way I can select ONLY names that have one first and last name (like the example I asked for).

Comment: Check the added `WHERE` clause in the updated answer.

Comment: Is it possible to make the switch again to the original from ''Keller,Max" to "Max Keller". A better thing would be to take everything after the comma and put it before. E.g. the name "Jon Keller,Max" -> "Max Jon Keller", or "Keller,Max Jon" -> "Max Jon Keller" . Thanks

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE(swapped_name, '^([^,]+),[ ]*(.*)$', '$2 $1')`